# How to install k9copy on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: software-installation, dependencies

I am trying to install k9copy but I get the following issue:

```
Error: Dependency is not satisfiable: libav-tools
```

If I perform `sudo apt-get install libav-tools` I get the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package libav-tools is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  ffmpeg:i386 ffmpeg

E: Package 'libav-tools' has no installation candidate
```

I already have FFmpeg installed (from the repositories) and there doesn't seem to be any guides online for how to resolve this.

Comment: k9copy is long dead, k9copy-reloaded probably dead. If you were to go here, download the 2017 .deb  ,  (- deb9u1)  for your arch & install from cli with **apt** it may work.. http://tomtomtom.org/k9copy-reloaded/en.html

Comment: @doug Seems I was downloading the 2015 .deb instead of the 2017 one. Hurrah, it works! Sorry for the dumb question.

Comment: Great, figure that 18.04 will probably be the last time that 2017 .deb will work in Ubuntu (- not a dumb question, in such cases always try newest available first.

Comment: If you get a chance write an answer to your question, then accept that answer. Has the dual benefit of providing a valid answer & will up your rep. points a bit. Maybe change question to "How to install k9-copy in 18.04"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As has been pointed out by [doug](https://askubuntu.com/users/27773/doug) it is still possible to use an 'unofficial' deb package for k9copy-reloaded (rather than the long defunct k9copy) under Bionic Beaver. Compiling from source would be another option but the benefits of compiling such an older application would probably not outweigh the considerable hassle.

Install this as follows:

```
wget http://tomtomtom.org/k9copy-reloaded/k9copy_3.0.3-1~deb9u1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i k9copy_3.0.3-1~deb9u1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
```

This installed well enough on my Bionic Beaver installation but to find the application in the Ubuntu 'Finder' some tweaks to the 2 desktop files are required (thanks to [cipricus](https://askubuntu.com/users/47206/cipricus) for the detective work!).

1. Fix for the k9copy desktop file:

   ```
   sudo sed -i_bak 's|Exec=k9copy -caption|Exec=k9copy|' \
        /usr/share/applications/k9copy.desktop
   ```
2. Fix for the k9copy assistant desktop file:

   ```
   sudo sed -i_bak 's|Exec=k9copy --assistant -caption|Exec=k9copy --assistant|' \
        /usr/share/applications/k9copy_assistant.desktop
   ```

And now all should be well. Gratuitous screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: +1 it works.. Only a bit different in my case. Or was it the same for you? `sudo dpkg -i` gave missing dependencies, so I had to do `sudo apt install libxine2 dvdauthor mplayer libxine2-ffmpeg`, and then `sudo apt --fix-broken install`  - that was all, no need for the last command.

Comment: @cipricus Glad you got it all working! Mind you `-f` and `--fix-broken` are actually the same options :)

Comment: the fact that it doesn't start normally is related to the form of the line `Exec=k9copy -caption "%c" %i %u` in `usr/share/applications/k9copy.desktop`. Changing that to a simple form like `Exec=k9copy` solves it.

Comment: @cipricus Genius :). The offender is the `-caption` option, writing up a correction right now...

Comment: sadly I cannot up-vote twice :)

Comment: I am a little sad at this as well :)

Comment: how do you launch k9copy once installed - I can't find it in my programs list on the desktop nor do I know the path to run it.

Answer (score 3):

The other answer here doesn't really work anymore for installing k9copy on 18.10, but there's an easier solution: there's an actually maintained (as of this writing) PPA at [https://launchpad.net/~tomtomtom/+archive/ubuntu/k9copy](https://launchpad.net/%7Etomtomtom/+archive/ubuntu/k9copy).

In Ubuntu 18.04, 18.10, 20.04 and 22.04 open the terminal and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tomtomtom/k9copy
sudo apt update
sudo apt install k9copy
```

Comment: This still works Sept 2020 (Ubuntu 18.04). Thanks!

Comment: not on 20.04 unfortunately, `The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/tomtomtom/k9copy/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.`

Comment: @karel It installs on Ubuntu 22.04 but first play with options copy or the assistant (rip and encode with x264/mp3 and ffmpeg) just crashes the program after start. What can I do?

Comment: My log says: `libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_14_0.VOB at 0x001c3d74
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_14_1.VOB at 0x001c3dc1
[..]
libdvdread: Found 15 VTS's
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
QFileDevice::seek: IODevice is not open
QIODevice::write (QTemporaryFile, ""): device not open`